# Getting raster layer path in ArcGIS Pro using C#

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, .net, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am creating an ArcGIS Pro Extension. I need to know the layer's path.
To get the layer path, code developed so far:

```c#
var pointLayer = MapView.Active.Map.Layers.OfType<FeatureLayer>().FirstOrDefault();
var rasterLayer = MapView.Active.Map.Layers.OfType<RasterLayer>().FirstOrDefault();
var pointLayerPath = await QueuedTask.Run(() => pointLayer.GetPath());
var rasterLayerPath = await QueuedTask.Run(() => rasterLayer.GetPath());
```

`pointLayerPath` is assigned the correct path but `rasterLayerPath` is assigned a null value.

How can I get the RasterLayer path?

Comment: You probably tried `MapView.Active.Map.Layers.GetLayersAsFlattenedList().OfType<RasterLayer>().FirstOrDefault();` and it didn't work, right?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, If you mean MapView.Active.Map.GetLayersAsFlattenedList().OfType<RasterLayer>().FirstOrDefault();
yes, I tried with this and  the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way for getting a file-based raster layer path from ***GintautasKmieliauskas***
answer in [ESRI Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-sdk-questions/getting-raster-layer-path-in-arcgis-pro-using-c/m-p/1121275#M7395).

```c#
var demLayer = MapView.Active.Map.Layers.OfType<RasterLayer>().FirstOrDefault(); 
var demPath =  QueuedTask.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string rasterLayerPath = string.Empty;
                    CIMDataConnection dataConnection = demLayer.GetDataConnection();
                    if (dataConnection is CIMStandardDataConnection)
                    {
                        CIMStandardDataConnection dataSConnection = dataConnection as CIMStandardDataConnection;

                        string sConnection = dataSConnection.WorkspaceConnectionString;

                        var wFactory = dataSConnection.WorkspaceFactory;
                        if (wFactory == WorkspaceFactory.Raster)
                        {
                            string sWorkspaceName = sConnection.Split('=')[1];

                            string sTable = dataSConnection.Dataset;

                            rasterLayerPath = Path.Combine(sWorkspaceName, sTable);
                        }
                    }

                    return rasterLayerPath;
                }
```

**UPDATE:** This code is working in latest version.

```c#
var rasterLayerPath = await QueuedTask.Run(() => rasterLayer.GetPath());
```